# DataContractSerializer backward compatibility

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

I am trying to deserialize from an older version of a serialized object, and I get an error elementNameX_backField is not expected, expecting element newElementName_backingField. Here is how my code looks like:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fullName, FileMode.Open))
                using (var decryptStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                using (var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(decryptStream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
                {

                    var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(classA), KnownTypes);
                    rv = ser.ReadObject(reader) as classA;
                }
[DataContract]
public class classA
{
 [DataMember]
 public classB ClassBee {get; set;}
}
[Serializable]
public class ClassB
{
[XmlElement("element")]
public customType1 elementNameX{get; set;}
[XmlElement("newElement")]
public customType2 newElementName{get; set;}
}
```

Any ideas, on how I could make it ignore newElement if it doesn't exist in the already serialized file?

Comment: I don't know, without trying random things, an easy way out of that - but the main problem here is that `ClassB` is not a data-contract with explicit data-members. Which makes it trickier.

Comment: In addition to what @MarcGravell said, [Serializable] types have their *fields* serialized by the DataContractSerializer, not their properties, and all the [XmlElement] attributes are ignored (they're enforced by the XmlSerializer, not by the DataContractSerializer).

Comment: classB is a third party class, which has it's own xml serialization scheme. I will try adding DataContract attribute to ClassB and see if that makes a difference. Thanks!

Comment: @Ladder IIRC it will get upset by that. And it won't really help with the fields issue. Tell me... Are the customs types the same? Is it just the member names that have changed? Or are the old/new values unrelated?

Comment: That actually fixed it! I don't know how, but I am glad it did! both XML serialization and DataContractSerialization work on that ClassB now

Comment: @LadderLogic, convert the comments to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the above comments for posterity:
 Adding DataContract attribute to ClassB fixed this issue. Both XML serialization and DataContractSerialization work on that ClassB now